# if year exists fill with the four trimester even if not exists bills in some month

Tags: sql, hsqldb

As I said in the title, I want to show all sum(bills) grouped by trimester and year but if there are no bills in one trimester show as: Trimester 2 amount = 0

My query (what I am trying):

```
select * from (

select "year",'1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 1 and 3 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 4 and 6 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 7 and 9 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 10 and 12 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"
)
order by 1 desc, 2 asc
```

The result that I'm getting is this:

```
year    Trimestre      base    iva    total
2017    1er Trimestre  101     23     124
2016    1er Trimestre  10      2.1    12.1
2016    2º Trimestre   30      6.3    36.3
2016    3er Trimestre  10      2.1    12.1
2016    4º Trimestre   20      4.2    24.1
```

And what I really want is this:

```
year    Trimestre      base    iva    total
2017    1er Trimestre  101     23     124
2017    2º Trimestre   0       0      0
2017    3er Trimestre  0       0      0
2017    4º Trimestre   0       0      0
2016    1er Trimestre  10      2.1    12.1
2016    2º Trimestre   30      6.3    36.3
2016    3er Trimestre  10      2.1    12.1
2016    4º Trimestre   20      4.2    24.1
```

Thanks for reading, I'll be waiting for your help :)

Tip: 1er Trimestre = first trimester, 2º Trimestre = second trimester, 3er Trimestre = 3rd trimester and 4º Trimestre = 4th trimester.

Also tried this:

```
select * from (

select "year",'1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 1 and 3 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 4 and 6 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 7 and 9 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 10 and 12 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"
) as "datos" right outer join (select distinct '1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre" from "Facturas" 
union all 
select distinct '2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre" from "Facturas" 
union all 
select distinct '3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre" from "Facturas" 
union all 
select distinct '4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre" from "Facturas" ) as "trimestres"
on "datos"."Trimestre" = "trimestres"."Trimestre"
order by 1 desc, 2 asc
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using HSQL (with OpenOffice base)

Comment: I'd create a trimestre table with 4 rows, having the values 1 to 4. Outer join with that table!

Comment: @jarlh I'll try something with that that you said and then ill say you if it worked :D

Comment: @AlbertoLópezPérez HSQLDB supports CTEs, this will save you from creating a separate table...

Comment: @jarlh Question updated, check it please. The result of the second table are the 4 rows of the trimesters.

Comment: @JohnHC: OpenOffice uses an extremely old version of HSQLDB (1.8) that does not support CTEs

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but I imported HSQLDB 2.3.4 with the jar file to my OpenOffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked!:

```
select "year","Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (

select "year",'1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 1 and 3 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 4 and 6 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 7 and 9 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

select "year",'4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total" from (Select Year("p_fpagado") as "year",month("p_fpagado") as "month",COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" where "p_pagado" = True and month("p_fpagado") between 10 and 12 group by Year("p_fpagado"),month("p_fpagado")) group by "year"

union all

(select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0) 
) group by "year","Trimestre" order by "year" desc,"Trimestre" asc
```

I made another "Union all" followed by:

```
(select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'1er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'2º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'3er Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0

union all

select distinct year("p_fpagado") as "year",'4º Trimestre' as "Trimestre",0 as "base",0 as "iva",0 as "total" from "Facturas" having year("p_fpagado") != 0) 
)
```

That is the table with all years that exists in the table where I want to get the values.

Then I grouped all with "()" and made as a table to select from there --> "()" and selected the following line:

```
select "year","Trimestre",COALESCE(sum("base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("iva"),0) as "iva",COALESCE(sum("total"),0) as "total"
```

And I got it. Thanks all for trying to help me!

I hope this answer is helpful to anyone with a similar problem. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer as you do not provide sample table data. You can work out the details yourself. HSQLDB has a number of features that you can use to avoid long and complex queries.

The YEAR(date) and QUARTER(date) functions can be used to extract the parts of the date for grouping.

The UNNEST keyword together with the SEQUENCE_ARRAY(start, end, interval) function can be used to generate the quarters in case the data is empty.

First part is the table with list of quarters:

```
SELECT YEAR(D) "y", QUARTER(D) "q", CASE QUARTER(D) WHEN 1 THEN '1st' WHEN 2 THEN '2nd' WHEN 3 THEN '3rd' WHEN 4 THEN '4th' END CASE "qname" 
FROM UNNEST(SEQUENCE_ARRAY(DATE'2016-01-01', DATE'2017-12-31' , 3 MONTH)) AS T(D)
```

The second part is a simpler query to get all your totals and counts without the labels:

```
SELECT YEAR("p_fpagado") as "year",  QUARTER("p_fpagado") as "quarter",
COALESCE(sum("im_base"),0) as "base",COALESCE(sum("im_calculado"),0) as "iva",
COALESCE(sum("im_total"),0) as "total" from "Facturas" WHERE "p_pagado" = TRUE  
GROUP BY YEAR("p_fpagado"),QUARTER("p_fpagado")
```

Then you need to LEFT JOIN your table to the list of quarters and add the required columns to the SELECT list:

```
WITH list_of_quarters AS (SELECT ....), calculated_data AS (SELECT ....)
SELECT "y", "qname", .... FROM list_of_quarters LEFT JOIN calculated_data ON (list_of_quarters."y" = calculated_data."year" AND list_of_quarters."q" = calculated_data."quarter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    ;WITH cteYears
        AS
        (
        SELECT [year] = 2016
        UNION ALL SELECT [year] = 2017
        ),
        cteTrimestres
        AS
        (
        SELECT TID = 1, Trimestre = '1er Trimestre'
        UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2º Trimestre'
        UNION ALL SELECT 3, '3er Trimestre'
        UNION ALL SELECT 4, '4º Trimestre'
        ),
        cteDataToAggregate
        AS
        (
        SELECT [year] = 2017, TID = 1, base = 101, iva = 23, total = 124
        UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 1, 10, 2.1, 12.1
        UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 2, 30, 6.3, 36.3
        UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 3, 10, 2.1, 12.1
        UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 4, 20, 4.2, 24.1
        ),
        cteDateRange
        AS
        (
        SELECT TID, [year], Trimestre
            FROM cteYears
                CROSS JOIN cteTrimestres
        )
        SELECT dr.[year],
            dr.Trimestre,
            base = ISNULL(SUM(a.base), 0),
            iva = ISNULL(SUM(a.iva), 0),
            total = ISNULL(SUM(a.total), 0)
            FROM cteDateRange AS dr
                LEFT OUTER JOIN cteDataToAggregate AS a
                    ON dr.[year] = a.[year]
                    AND dr.TID = a.TID
            GROUP BY dr.[year],
                dr.Trimestre
            ORDER BY [year] DESC,
                Trimestre;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to put this code at the end of mine and the program gives me errors "Unexpected token With". can u put all the code that should work please? (sorry, I didn't worked before with "with" clause)

Comment: Sure.  See my second post.  By the way, I'm testing this code using MS SQL Server, so I'm not sure how it will work in HSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same logic without Common Table Expressions...

```
    SELECT cteDateRange.[year],
        cteDateRange.Trimestre,
        base = ISNULL(SUM(cteDataToAggregate.base), 0),
        iva = ISNULL(SUM(cteDataToAggregate.iva), 0),
        total = ISNULL(SUM(cteDataToAggregate.total), 0)
        FROM (
            SELECT TID, [year], Trimestre
                FROM (  
                    SELECT [year] = 2016
                    UNION ALL SELECT [year] = 2017
                    ) AS cteYears
                CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT TID = 1, Trimestre = '1er Trimestre'
                    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2º Trimestre'
                    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '3er Trimestre'
                    UNION ALL SELECT 4, '4º Trimestre'
                    ) AS cteTrimestres
            ) AS cteDateRange
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT [year] = 2017, TID = 1, base = 101, iva = 23, total = 124
                UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 1, 10, 2.1, 12.1
                UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 2, 30, 6.3, 36.3
                UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 3, 10, 2.1, 12.1
                UNION ALL SELECT 2016, TID = 4, 20, 4.2, 24.1
            ) AS cteDataToAggregate
            ON cteDateRange.[year] = cteDataToAggregate.[year]
            AND cteDateRange.TID = cteDataToAggregate.TID
        GROUP BY cteDateRange.[year],
            cteDateRange.Trimestre
        ORDER BY [year] DESC,
            Trimestre
```

Comment: Can't use ISNULL --> Access denied in statement ISNULL

Comment: Try replacing ISNULL with COALESCE.

Comment: Fixed but now giving this: Unexpected Union, requires from in statement [ (full query)]

Comment: My UNION ALL statements were merely an attempt to get your data into my SQL Server instance.  You can replace cteYears and cteTrimestres with actual tables populated appropriately.  Of course you may have this data in your database already?

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL and won't work in HSQLDB